# Find function with a degree of 4 from three statements

Tags: functions, polynomials

If $f(x)$ is a function/polynomial with a degree of **4** and:
$$f(-1)=1$$
$$f(-2)=4$$
$$f(-3)=9$$
How can I find $f(x)$?

---

From statement 1, I know $f(x) = (x+1)(...)+1$

With statement 2, I know $f(x) = (x+1)[(x+2)(...)-3]+1$

We can use a similar way to find $f(x)$ with statement 3, but don't we end up with a **cubic** polynomial?

If my calculations are correct, how can we turn the cubic into a 4 degree polynomial?

Comment: Use $(x + 1)^{2}$ instead of $x + 1$ or something.

Comment: What's quatric? You mean quadratic? It can't be quartic 'cause it needs 5.

Comment: I think it is quadratic because$3$ isn't enough for quadric

Comment: $f(x) = x^{2}$?

Comment: We know that $f(x)-x^2$ has roots at $-1,-2,-3$. So, $$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\mid f(x)-x^2$$This isn't enough info to determine $f$.

Comment: Sorry guys I made some critical typo and forgot to add some other statements. However, @DonThousand still got a solution that matches what I want. Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $f(x)-x^2$ has roots at $-1,-2,-3$. So, $$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\mid f(x)-x^2$$

What does this tell us? There's exactly one polynomial that has degree $<3$ that satisfies the conditions, which is $x^2$. There's exactly one cubic polynomial, up to constant multiplication, that satisfies the conditions as well, notably $c(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+x^2$ (for any constant $c$).

All we know is that any $f$ of degree $4$ must be of the form $$c(x+a)(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+x^2$$for some constants $a,c$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a plain application of [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Three statements make it possible to uniquely define a polynomial of degree $2$. You can still find all the polynomial of degree $n\geq 2$ that satisfy those statements (using the Lagrange basis for example).

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $4$, then

$$f(x)=b(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x-c)+x^2,$$

where $b,c \in \mathbb R$ are arbitrary.

But if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, then

$$f(x)=x^2$$

is uniquely detemined by the above conditions.

Comment: You can also multiply the quartic term by an arbitrary constant

Comment: Yes, you are right !

Answer (score -1):

**In this answer, I will determine the necessary and sufficient condition for the polynomial degree to be at least $4.$**

I considered your polynomial to be a **quartic** of at least degree $4.$ But, this is not enough.

## Method

For the quartic polynomial, at least value of $f(-4)$ must be known. Let, $f(-4)=p$, then you have

$$f(x)=a(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+x^2$$

$$\implies a×(-6)+16=p$$

$$\implies a=\dfrac {16-p}{6}$$

$$\implies f(x)=\left(\dfrac {16-p}{6}\right)(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+x^2$$

But, this is still not enough. Because, we have a cubic polynomial. You still need value of $f(-5).$

Let,

$$f(-5)=\left(\dfrac {16-p}{6}\right)\times (-24)+25\Longrightarrow f(-5)=4p-39$$

So, if $f(-5)=4f(-4)-39$ you still have a cubic polynomial.

Let, $f(-4)=p$ and $f(-5)≠4f(-4)-39$, then our tricky method will not work. So, you need a general method.

$$\begin{cases} a-b+c-d+e=1 \\16a-8b+4c-2d+e=4\\ 81a-27b+9c-3d+e=9 \\ 256a-64b+16c-4d+e=f(-4)\\ 625a-125b+25c-5d+e=f(-5) \end{cases}$$

You can solve this linear system with Gauss method.

## A necessary and sufficient condition:

At least the values of  ​​$f(-4)$ and $f(-5)$ must be given and the following condition must be hold:

$$f(-5)-4f(-4)+39≠0.$$

## Conclusion

To obtain a polynomial of degree of at least $4$, it is necessary to know at least the values ​​of $f(-4)$ and $f (-5)$, where $f(-5)≠4f(-4)-39$ or $f(-5)-4f(-4)+39≠0.$

To adapt to your circumstances, I wrote $f (-4)$ and $f(-5)$ instead of $f(4)$ and $f(5).$

Let's test the necessary and sufficient condition.

Let,  $$ f(-1)=1 \\ f(-2)=4 \\ f(-3)=9\\ f(-4)=16 \\ f(-5)=25 $$

Then, we have,

$$f(5)-4f(-4)+39 \Longrightarrow 25-4 \times 16+39=0$$

As it seems, the necessary and sufficient condition are not provided.  So, we can find a lower degree polynomial. And we really have such a function:

For example, the function $f(x)=x^2$ is the simplest function that provides the values ​​we give.

## Remark

Here we have only examined the requirement to give at least $f(-4)$ and $f(-5)$ values.  However, it is also possible to write it for the cases $f(4)$ and $f(5)$, or $f(7)$ and $f(9)$. However, this can never invalidate the condition $f(-5)-4f(-4)+39≠0.$

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. Are you providing an example of a polynomial that satisfies the conditions? There's a simpler one ($f(x)=x^2$). And, you can compute what $f(4)$ is given your choice of polynomial.

Comment: @DonThousand if $f(-4)$ and $f(-5)$ are arbitrary ,we can not compute.

Comment: You changed this answer after I commented, my comment isn't relevant any more. This answer is overkill, though. The key realization is that of O'Haran's answer.

Comment: @DonThousand I checked all the cases.  I set a condition for the degree to be at least $4.$